# Mysql joins thread inbox

Tags: mysql, join, case

I am building af facebook thread like system.

My issue is that when `conv_fromid` or `conv_toid` is the same as the logged in userid,
it prints the wrong username. So I'm searching for a some kind of switch method. I don't know if you/I can use sql case?

Basicly the problem is:

- when the logged in userid equals to conv_fromid, it needs to join pub_users based on conv_toid(not conv_fromid again)
- if the logged in userid is equals to conv_toid it needs to join pub_users based on conv_fromid.

My Request :

```
SELECT * FROM pub_conversations a
        INNER JOIN pub_users b
            ON a.conv_toid = b.user_id
        WHERE conv_fromid ='". get_uid() ."'
        OR conv_toid='". get_uid() ."'
```

So what the output should end up with, is a list of all the users the logged in user have an conversation with

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/feb21

Comment: Why not just create a conversation table so that you can easily group all of your messages. Then you will be able to add in features for 3+ users per conversation and pulling all messages would be easier.

Comment: I have both Conversation and message table, so i am able to group them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pub_conversations a
        INNER JOIN pub_users b
          ON a.conv_toid = b.user_id AND conv_fromid ='". get_uid() ."'
          OR a.conv_toid='". get_uid() ."'
```

I`m not sure I have a brain melt this evening:

```
SELECT * FROM pub_conversations a
        INNER JOIN pub_users b
          ON a.conv_toid = b.user_id AND conv_fromid ='". get_uid() ."'
          OR a.conv_toid='". get_uid() ."' AND conv_fromid != b.user_id


SELECT * FROM pub_conversations a
        INNER JOIN pub_users b
            ON b.user_id =(
CASE
 WHEN `conv_fromid`='". get_uid() ."' THEN `conv_toid`
 WHEN  `conv_toid`='". get_uid() ."' THEN `conv_fromid` ELSE -1 
END
)
```

Comment: Hmm... When i use your examples, On one user it outputs all usernames that you do not have a conversation with, and another user it shows the users you have a conversation with - Strange :P

Comment: Could you make a small fiddle?

Comment: Where is it possible to make a sql fiddle? :D

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using

```
SELECT * FROM pub_users a, pub_conversations b
    WHERE (CASE WHEN b.conv_fromid = ". get_uid() ." THEN b.conv_toid ELSE b.conv_fromid END) = a.user_id
```

Thanks anyway for your time :)